# How to get specific data on separate excel worksheet from access reports

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have a table with multiple fields and records and I have created a form and report. Now, I want to have:

1. all the records available in the table in *sheet1* of Excel
2. on the next worksheet I want only those items which are due in the coming week and coming month, and
3. on the next worksheet I want important or high severity items.

I have tried page breaks and grouping but the data is showing in the same worksheet in Excel. How do I store data in separate worksheets of the same workbook?

Comment: This is extremely vague. Care to edit your question to include an example?

Answer (score 1):

I've created the following to represent your Access table:

[image]

I've then created a query for items due in 1 month:

[image]

```sql
SELECT tblItems.ItemID, tblItems.ItemDescription, tblItems.DueDate, tblItems.Importance
FROM tblItems
WHERE tblItems.DueDate<DateAdd("m",1,Now());
```

...and then another query for items of high importance:

[image]

```sql
SELECT tblItems.ItemID, tblItems.ItemDescription, tblItems.DueDate, tblItems.Importance
FROM tblItems
WHERE (((tblItems.Importance)="High"));
```

This gives us 3 datasets, which can be linked to an Excel workbook in separate worksheets.

In your Excel workbook, in *Sheet1* where you want all records, you can go to the *Data* tab and then in the *Get External Data* group, click the *From Access* button:

[image]

In the dialogue window, navigate to your Access file that has your datasets and click open.

You should then get a list of tables/queries available for you to link to. For the all records worksheet (*Sheet1*) we can link to `tblItems` as that has all our records in this example:

[image]

Excel will ask you how you want to view the data (table will be fine) and where you want the data placed (cell `A1` in *Sheet1* will be fine):

[image]

This should then bring the data from Access in to your Excel workbook:

[image]

You can then repeat the above steps for *Sheet2* and *Sheet3* respectively for the 2 remaining queries:

*Sheet2* - items due in 1 month:

[image]

*Sheet3* - items of high importance:

[image]

If you change any of this data in Access, you can easily see these changes in Excel by going to the *Data* tab again and clicking *Refresh All*:

[image]